# Why MAMP (PRO) restarts MySQL when changing PHP config? (And how to prevent that?)

Tags: mamp-pro

Every time I change **any** config in PHP or Apache sections, MAMP asks to restart MySQL (and all the other services).

Is there any way to prevent that? (Using MAMP PRO 4.2.1 on MacOs High Sierra)

I'm not supposed to restart my mySQL if I add a new entry on etc/hosts for instance.

(Besides the fact that MAMP crashes 5/10 times it tries to restart the whole thing, and 10/10 times can't restart MySQL properly.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide this anecdotal experience. 
I was having the same issue. I deleted old hosts from about 16 down to 6. I also deleted unused sql databases ( 16 to 6 ) MAMP continued to hang but eventually pulled out of the hang after the moste recent database update.

First I ran a system clean with Cocktail –wiping caches and any system DNS caches and rebooted. Then with phpMyAdmin I deleted old databases restarted the servers and then updated the current database project after manually dropping all the tables. I suspected that mysqld was the cause of the hang and when i examined the process records it was difficult to be sure. I think there are issues with memory swapping and addresses based on my guestimate.

I'm about to ditch MAMP for Docker when i get a bit of time to learn Docker.

Comment: We are on the same boat with Docker. :) I don't want to delete my databases, but stop mysqld from being restarted when I change a PHP or hosts settings (it does make sense, right?).